# Select text in div on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a problem, I'd like to select text that is inside a div, here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KL6G3/

html:

```
<div id="connect">some text some text: <div id="select" onmouseover="this.focus();this.select();">when you hover over therer, it gets selected</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#connect {
    resize: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    border: none;
}
#connnect:focus {
    border: none;
}
#select {
     display: inline-block;   
}
```

When I hover over #select, text doesnt get selected, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: div elements do not have a `select` method, you should check your console you would see an error about `undefined is not a function` or similar

Comment: so what elements does have select method? thanks

Comment: [inputs, textareas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.select) have the select method

Answer (score 1):

`this.focus();` and `this.select();` will only work for `input` and `textarea`.

Here is a simple way:

Assign `contenteditable` attribute to that particular element. If user set focus into `editable` div then content of editable div is selected.

```
<div contenteditable="true" onmouseover="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" id="connect">some text some text: <div>when you hover over therer, it gets selected</div></div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5cN2/3)**

Comment: Smart. Just one nitpick: OP wanted it be on mouseover, so I'd change your solution to: `onmouseover="this.focus();document.exec(...)`. Of course a persisting problem is that the content is *editable* and the user could inadvertently delete it...

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the selection? To highlight or to copy the text? You can use `CSS` to highlight and [zero clipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) to copy, and combine both of them, if you want highlight and copy to clipboard. Avoid `contenteditable` if it is not an editable area.

Comment: -1 because OP wants to select the text, whatever his intentions may be (so zeroclipboard is not necessarily suitable nor required), +1 because your comment about `contenteditable` makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: Thanks @Tyblitz, I agree with you and rephrased the answer.